# iOS 7 : Multipeer connectivity - Multiple Sessions?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to create an via iOS7 multipeer connnectivity where:

1. Browser1 can see Advertiser1 and Advertiser2
2. Browser1 sends an invite to Advertiser1 and is approved
3. Browser1 sends an invite to Advertiser2 and is approved
4. Browser1 can send messages to Advertiser1 and Advertiser2 separately

All the examples I've seen show the creation of a single MCSession when the MCNearbyServiceAdvertiser and MCNearbyServiceBrowser are initialized.

My question is: it it possible to have an array to maintain multiple sessions between groups of devices? If so, where should I be creating the new MCSession objects?

Comment: Yes it is. The example Apple application for this Framework does exactly what you're asking. Multiple sessions per device (in the case of the app, a chatroom)

Comment: @Jeff, you should repost this as an answer to give it more visibility.

Answer (score 4):

The Apple sample application for the `MCMultipeerConnectivity` framework contains the use-case you describe.

They create a wrapper class to handle the `MCSession`, and each `MCSession` maintains an array of connected `MCPeerIDs`.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html

Comment: hi, do you know of any sample code projects for the MultipeerGroupChat in Swift?